# How to access a Vuex data property from another Vuex data property?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I store my color variables in an array called "colors[]" in the vuex store for easy access throughout my vue app. This works fine when I access those colors inside components methods or inline style.

Now I store an array of objects in my Vuex store called "priorities[{}]". Each of the priorities has a color attached to it like "green" etc. The hex values of the this colors variables should be from the "colors" array in my vuex store.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
  colors: {
      blue: '#1f96ff',
      green: '#0DAA54',
      orange: '#F49D3A',
      red: '#FF2833',
      purple: '#5E57BA',
      pink: '#B539AC'
  },
  priorities: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Low',
        value: 10,
        color: THIS SHOUD LINK TO colors.green        
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Medium',
        value: 20,
        color: THIS SHOUD LINK TO colors.orange           
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'High',
        value: 30,
        color: THIS SHOUD LINK TO colors.red     
      }
    }
  }
```

So, I basically tried everything from this.$store.state.colors to state.colors
But it seems to me that this is generally not working. However how would one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way but you can store the color hex mapping in a seperate object.

```
const colors = {
      blue: '#1f96ff',
      green: '#0DAA54',
      orange: '#F49D3A',
      red: '#FF2833',
      purple: '#5E57BA',
      pink: '#B539AC'
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
  colors: colors,
  priorities: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Low',
        value: 10,
        color: colors.green        
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Medium',
        value: 20,
        color: colors.orange           
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'High',
        value: 30,
        color: colors.red     
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: With this, priorities will not become `reactive` which will cause a problem. Using this approach, if you mutate, the value of `colors`, the value of `priorities` will not change based on the new values of `colors`.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag what makes you think that it will not be reactive anymore?

Comment: I don't think user will change the hex value of `green` color on the go. But surely he might add some more colors and priorities or modify the existing priority. What do you think? @JulianPaoloDayag

Comment: It's not about what you think, but the possibility. It is possible that the user will change the color, and will add more dynamically.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag I guess let the OP decide that. With every problem there is a use case associated and a good tradeoff between things is always a need.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that.

Comment: I will go with voids solution as colors is a constant for us determined by our UI team not the users and I feel the solution is a bit simpler. Thanks anyways I was really stuck on this!

Answer (score 3):

Move your `priorities` to [`getters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html).

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    colors: {
      blue: '#1f96ff',
      green: '#0DAA54',
      orange: '#F49D3A',
      red: '#FF2833',
      purple: '#5E57BA',
      pink: '#B539AC'
    },
    priorities: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Low',
        value: 10,
        color: 'green'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Medium',
        value: 20,
        color: 'orange'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'High',
        value: 30,
        color: 'red'
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    prioritiesWithColors(state) {
      return state.priorities.map((priority) => {
        priority.color = state.colors[priority.color];
        return priority
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
this.$store.getters.prioritiesWithColors
```

Comment: State is different then getters? In case if user would want to add / modify something to priority then how would he do it?

Comment: Ja, I thought about that too. But than I cannot dynamically add new priorities

Comment: You can now add more priorities, by mutating the `priorities` state. And you can use the `prioritiesWithColors` getter if you want to use priorities with the color based from the `colors` state.

Comment: This solution works fine! I just choose to go with the constant outside of the vuex store as in our use case it is simpler because we don't change the colors dynamically from the users side.

Comment: Sure, no problem.